# C# File.Move firewall port

Tags: c#, .net, firewall

I need to copy and/or move files across servers to the other side of my
firewall. I was wondering if anyone can tell me what port(s) I will need to
open to run these methods in my C# program?

```
class MoveIt
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var localPath = @"c:\temp\";
        var remotePath = @"\\MyRemoteServer\MyShare\MyPath\"

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(localPath + "MyTestFile.txt") &&
                Directory.Exists(remotePath))
            {
                File.Move(localPath + "MyTestFile.txt", remotePath + 
                "MyTestFile.txt");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Moving a file uses the SMB protocol.

Comment: This question does not show research effort. If you are having problems please post your current best guess. You should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least **TCP 445**, and to be *sure* you also want TCP 137-139, though this latter group is only if you're still stuck using NetBIOS for smb name resolution.